# How to Find Current Path within a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on this gem. What I need to do is get the current path.

In Rails I was able to do:

```
request.filtered_parameters["action"] + "_path"
```

And that gave me my current path.

Now that I'm inside of the gem, its not working anymore...

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: What gem? We need more information to help you. Provide a better example of your code that demonstrates the problem.